# How to format combined text date into date equivalent?

Tags: excel

I have a text in a cell like this

```
44691, 44669, 44670
```

I want it to represent as the date equivalent like this in one cell

```
March 10, 2022, April 18, 2022, April 19, 2022
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Those numbers are in one cell, all together?

Comment: Also please let us know what version you have.

Comment: 44691 is May 10, 2022?

Comment: Yeah they are all in one cell. @ScottCraner

Comment: @findwindow Yes when you format a cell as date it gives you May 10, 2022

Comment: To avoid confusion, please update your post with correct outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may ***try*** this formula, assuming you're using **O365**

[image]

• Formula used in cell **B7**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),"mmmm dd, yyyy"))
```

Or, If you are using **O365** & presently in **Office Insiders, Beta Channel Version**, then may try this as well

• Formula used in cell **B3**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXT(TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),"mmmm dd, yyyy"))
```